# How to force ST_Intersects to use spatial index instead of normal btree index?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a table which stores ST_Buffer of 22km radius (SRID = 4326). I'm trying the following query:

```
line = "ST_GeometryFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(%s)')" % (line)
cur.execute("SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Difference(line,(SELECT ST_Union(buffers.the_geog::geometry)  
FROM buffers WHERE ST_Intersects( line ,buffers.the_geog::geometry )))) FROM %s as line"%(line))
```

The `EXPlAIN ANALYZE` query gave the following result:

```
[('Function Scan on line  (cost=0.00..2741841.15 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=10345.785..10345.789 rows=1 loops=1)',), 
('  SubPlan 1',), ('    ->  Aggregate  (cost=2741841.12..2741841.13 rows=1 width=576) (actual time=10345.434..10345.435 rows=1 loops=1)',), 
('          ->  Seq Scan on buffers  (cost=0.00..2741839.82 rows=261 width=576) (actual time=920.965..10051.716 rows=841 loops=1)',), 
('                Filter: ((line.line && (the_geog)::geometry) AND _st_intersects(line.line, (the_geog)::geometry))',), 
('                Rows Removed by Filter: 7814377',), ('Total runtime: 10346.496 ms',)]
```

As you can see `ST_Intersects` is not using the `GIST` index. How can I force the query to use `GIST` index ?

My table structure is:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE buffers(gid serial PRIMARY KEY, the_geog geography(POLYGON,4326) );")
```

Index is:

```
CREATE INDEX tindex ON buffer USING GIST ( the_geog );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did run analyze, it is probably because of the subquery. When you write the query without a subquery, it will use the spatial index. Something like this:

```
select ST_AsText(ST_Difference(line.line, ST_Union(buffers.the_geom::geometry))) 
FROM line,buffers WHERE 
ST_Intersects( line.line ,buffers.the_geom::geometry )
group by line.line;
```